# Reference Xcode version number from Jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

I'm trying to get a reference to my Xcode projects CFBundleVersionString or CFBundleVersion within my Jenkins Build.

My goal is to be able to set the build numbers in this sort of fashion ${CFBundleVersionString}.${build_number}. This way the Version is dictated by the project and the build number is added on when the project is built.

Is this possible at all? I know that you can reference ${build_number}. Also I know that I could include a parameter in the build that is dictated, but I would prefer it all be managed through the Xcode project since our builds are triggered by github commits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read CFBundleVersionString from your Info.plist file with:

```
export VERSION=`defaults read ${INFO_PLIST} CFBundleVersionString`
```

output this to a property file:

```
echo VERSION=$VERSION > version.properties
```

and use this file to inject environment variables to your jenkins build.
You can then use this variable with [Build Name Setter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin) or simply us it in build mails.

Similarly you can update the version inside the plist with:

```
defaults write ${INFO_PLIST} CFBundleVersionString ${VERSION}.${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

Comment: How would I go about injecting the properties from the file into the Jenkins build process?? I'm assuming the Export commands are just run from the shell command?

Comment: Where would I add the two lines above to get them to output that file? At what point in the process in Jenkins or do I use those within Xcode?

Comment: You do this in Jenkins 'Execute Shell' build step. this should probably happen after invoking Xcode. And use the EnvInject step after that to inject variables from the version.properties file.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the [Xcode Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin), you have `CFBundleVersion` available as $VERSION and `CFBundleShortVersionString` as $SHORT_VERSION.

I found $SHORT_VERSION by searching the [XCode Plugin source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/xcode-plugin/blob/8ce2166f40d01a7d253717691b254b34b8ca92ea/src/main/java/au/com/rayh/XCodeBuilder.java#L691).

Comment: I see where you are referencing this in the Xcode Plugin source code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @JamesParker - just checking, but are you referencing these variables in a step that follows after the Xcode Plugin has set the variable. Also, I used the $SHORT_VERSION variable in the naming of my archived .ipa file, which occurs within the Xcode Plugin's build step.  Perhaps these variables are only accessible within the Xcode Plugin's build step? and not as environment variables to all of Jenkins's build steps?  If that is so, I will update the answer, and would request to vote back up accordingly. Cheers

Comment: I'm referencing them in the Versioning option which is part of the XCode Plugin.

Comment: Why do you need these variables in the Versioning option section if its automatically using the CFBundleShortVersionString  when leaving it blank?  In any case, I'm using these variables in the Xcode "general build settings" under ".ipa filename pattern".  It says there "You may use ${VERSION} and ${BUILD_DATE} (yyyy.MM.dd) in this string"

Comment: I see, my oversight. If I find a solution, will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking everywhere for something that works from Jenkins.

shortversionnumber=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print CFBundleShortVersionString" ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}`

But if your build has not happened yet, you will need to manually specify the location of the plist file.

That is all!