# Getting CFBundleVersion from within Jenkins to use it as a variable, something like ${APP_VERSION}

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration, plist

What I'd like to do is to be able to add a tag to commits which Jenkins is building from. Right now I tag commits with the Jenkins build number but I want to also add in the app version as listed in the Info.plist CFBundleVersion in front of that.

What I want to know is, how I can grab that value using Jenkins or otherwise and be able to use that as a parameter/variable within Jenkins?

I've seen references to using plistbuddy to set this value so I would assume there's a way to use that to get the same value. Though how and how to get that to where I can use it in Jenkins I don't know.

---

For further clarification I am using Git Publisher in Jenkins to create a tag and push it with this format

jenkinsbuild-$BUILD_NUMBER

This results in a tag on the commit in git like this - jenkinsbuild-303

What I want, assuming my app is currently at version 3.5 is a tag that reads - jenkinsbuild-3.5-303

Comment: Have you installed Xcode Plugin? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin

Comment: Yes I have that installed

Comment: Would you mind setting an example? I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I've added something extra that hopefully helps. What I am not looking to do is change the values in the plist itself, merely to read them and be able to use them to create the tab like how I'm using $BUILD_NUMBER above.

Comment: I think here you can find your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536041/reference-xcode-version-number-from-jenkins

Comment: That looked right, but I didn't know what to do with that information or where to add it within Jenkins to get it to produce the version.properties file. I added a comment to that effect already but wasn't sure anyone would pick up on it so posted my own question.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to piece together a solution from the answer which @agy linked to. Here's what I did:

1. In the Build section for the Jenkins configuration, I added the following two lines to an 'Execute Shell' step *after* the Xcode step:

   ```
   APP_VERSION=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :CFBundleShortVersionString" "path to your plist")    
   echo APP_VERSION=$APP_VERSION > appversion.properties;
   ```
2. After that, I added an 'Inject Environment Variables' step (I think this is part of the EnvInject plugin), to which I added "appversion.properties" to the **Properties File Path** field.
3. After this is done, **APP_VERSION** is now available as an environment variable in subsequent shell command steps.