# Xcode: how to include build number in app name

Tags: xcode

I'm rolling out beta releases of a Mac app, and would like to include the current build number in the app name, e.g. what the users see as app name in the dock etc.

if my app is named `The App`, I want it to show `The App Beta 1234`

so in the target's build config, there is "Product Name" which has a value of `$(TARGET_NAME)`

now, on a debug build, I would like to add the build number there. This should be possible using `$(TARGET_NAME) Beta $(????)`.

what do I put there instead of the `????`? Or is it not so simple?

e.g. there's this: [Getting CFBundleVersion from within Jenkins to use it as a variable, something like ${APP_VERSION}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30846017/getting-cfbundleversion-from-within-jenkins-to-use-it-as-a-variable-something-l)

but, I'm not using Jenkins, and also it looks somehow wonky. Is that the only/proper way to access CFBundleVersion...?

Comment: Try ${PRODUCT_NAME}  ${CFBundleVersion} on key CFBundleDisplayName

Comment: just tried, unfortunately not working.

Comment: along with $(TARGET_NAME) did you try ...Try with paranthesis intead of flower bracket

Comment: yes.. well what's funny is, neither Bundle name or Bundle Display Name seem to have an effect on the name shown on the app file/bundle. But tweaking Product Name in the target build settings does have an effect. Just seems like I can't acces the build number there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things you can do:

---

### 1) Modify `CFBundleName` using a build phase

- Select the target you want to modify within Xcode
- Open the Build Phases for the selected target
- Add a new *Run Script* Build Phase
- Paste the following code

`BUILD_NUMBER=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleName $PRODUCT_NAME Beta $BUILD_NUMBER" "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH"`

The script makes use of *PlistBuddy*. First, it gets the `CFBundleVersion` from your `Info.plist` and stores it in a variable `BUILD_NUMBER`. In the second step it uses *PlistBuddy* to set `CFBundleName` to `$PRODUCT_NAME Beta $BUILD_NUMBER`. Note that the it will **not** modify the original plist but the one in your build directory so you wont be bothered by changes in your git repository.

The `CFBundleName` will be displayed in the Menu Bar when the app is running. It will not have an effect on the App's name in the Dock (that is derived from the app's file name).

Note: This will probably not work if you have localized your Bundle Name using `CFBundleDisplayName`. You may need to adapt the script above in that case.

---

### 2) Use Custom Build Setting

- Select the target you want to modify
- Open Build Settings for selected target
- Editor --> Add Build Setting --> Add User-Defined Setting
- Name your new setting `CUSTOM_BUILD_VERSION` and add a value
- Search for `PRODUCT_NAME` in the Build Settings and change it to `$(TARGET_NAME) Beta $(CUSTOM_BUILD_VERSION)`
- Open your target's `Info.plist`
- Change `CFBundleVersion` to `$(CUSTOM_BUILD_VERSION)`
- If you want to change the build version, change `CUSTOM_BUILD_VERSION` instead

Using this method Xcode will create an app named "SomeApp Beta ". Because the name in the dock is the same as the app bundle name, the dock will also use that name.

---

### 3) Rename App after building

Of course you could also just rename the app after building it with Xcode. If you are building your app from the command line using Gradle (see the [gradle-xcodeplugin](https://github.com/openbakery/gradle-xcodePlugin)), [Fastlane](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane) or a custom build script this can of course be automated. 
It should be pretty easy to use PlistBuddy to extract the `CFBundleVersion` from the bundled app and then rename the bundle to include the extracted value. This should be fairly similar to the script from 1).

Comment: hey thanks! I'm using solution 2) currently, which is less than perfect since Xcode doesn't seem to pick up the custom variable in CFBundleVersion, e.g. it treats `$(CUSTOM_BUILD_VERSION)` as a string. Will try solution 1), seems to be the proper thing to do.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I tried that and did in fact inspect the `Info.plist` in the bundled app which showed the correct version. Did you look at the `Info.plist` of the app or just check in Xcode's target view? The target view will unfortunately not expand the variable and treats it as a string, as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Use $(TARGET_NAME) Beta $(BUILD_NUMBER)

Comment: this doesn't work for me. Xcode doesn't seem to see a variable named BUILD_NUMBER.